# Automatically sync text to video for subtitles

Tags: video-editor

I was wondering if there is any way I can sync a script in plain text to a video automatically. I just want software that will take the transcript and sync with the finished video. I use adobe creative cloud and right now for captions I use camtasia and moviecaptioner. Any automation will help.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a system that can identify the words spoken and match them to a text file?

Comment: Yes, a program that can take the words spoken and match them with a pre-written script I wrote.

Comment: The current top end speech recognition systems still need training to every person's voice, and are quite expensive. And none of them connect to video editing suites, so you'd need to write the conduit software yourself. I'd suggest hiring an intern...

Comment: Thanks... this would actually be a pretty decent idea to start a business on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for might be something like ScriptSync. It used to be included with Avid's Media Composer. These days you need to purchase it separately.

http://www.avid.com/US/industries/workflow/Scriptbased-Editing